# Implementing binary search with tolerance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, while-loop, binary-search

I'm trying to find a number between `min` and `max`. I only know (through using the `more` method) whether the number I'm guessing is higher or lower than the number passed. The number that I need to find *can* be a decimal, which is what is making me nervous, as the average binary search seems to mostly concern itself with the business of integers.

The algorithm I've written is an attempt at a binary search, without the array. The difference, as I see it, between a classical binary search is that the values and the index of the search have been conflated into the same task.

```js
var tolerance = 0;

var tries, min, max, current, needed;

function search () {

  tries = 0;
  min = 0;
  max = 100;
  needed = Math.random() * max;
  current = (max - min) / 2;

  while (!accept() && tries < 100) {

    if (more(current))
      min = current;
    else
      max = current;

    current = min + ((max - min) / 2);

    tries++;

  }

  results();

}

function more (n) {

  return n < needed;

}

function accept () {

  return Math.abs(current-needed) <= tolerance;

}

function results () {

  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 'accepted: ' + current + '<br>needed: ' + needed + '<br>tries: ' + tries;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="javascript:search();">search</button>
<br>
<div id="results"></div>
```

My question is this; given what I want to do, can this code be improved upon? Or perhaps there is a better way of doing this all together? Obviously, the number of tries is greatly improved by increasing the tolerance - but it's at the expense of the accuracy of the final result. For example, would it make sense for me to increase the tolerance after a certain number of tries?

Also, how best would one go about ensuring that the needed number is in range? I know I could ensure that `!more(max) && more(min)` before attempting the `while` loop, but is there a more efficient way than simply bolting on two extra checks at the beginning of the script?

Comment: I would change the accept function to `Math.abs(current-needed) <= tolerance` just for better readability.

Comment: @Wikunia you're right - that was a bit sloppy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Binary search hangs every time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193520/javascript-binary-search-hangs-every-time)

Comment: @Rishav This doesn't hang. My main question here is, can this be improved upon or are there better ways of achieving the same goal?

Comment: You might get better feedback from http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you want to happen if the number is out of range? Broaden the search?

Comment: @phenxd if the number is out of range then I'd like it to settle on either of the original `max` or `min` values, depending on which side of the range it falls.

Comment: Well then a simple validation makes a lot of sense IMO

Comment: @phenxd do you mean, implement two checks using the `more` method at the beginning of each search?

Comment: @dave thanks, I will try that tomorrow if the response here is poor. never knew about that stack exchange site.

Comment: Personnally, I'd rather validate that the number is in range before executing the search function. And you can use your more() function if you want, of course, but you could also use a clamp function such as (see link) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409895/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-cap-a-number-to-a-segment

Comment: @phenxd good idea. Thanks.

Comment: @shennan binary search _always_ works, just look at that code.

Comment: @Rishav ditto, I'm not using an array for the search. The index and the value in my search are conflated.

Comment: @shennan wait a minute.... you want to check whether a number is in between two other numbers? O.o What is the need of binary search there?

Comment: @Rishav I think you've misread the question and the code. If I've not been verbose enough then I apologise but other people have shown signs of understanding. Thanks for your suggestions anyway.

Comment: @shennan alright then, can you clarify your question. More specifically, since you are already generating a number between `min` and `max` (at least in this snippet), what is the purpose of this search? And if the number you are generating is truly random and you wish to check if it is within `min` and `max`, then what is wrong with something like `if (min <= needed && needed <= max)` ?

Comment: @Rishav the range checks are (in theory) external to the code base. I will be guessing numbers to an external API, so I will not have the `needed` variable in practise. It's exposure in this script is purely to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: @shennan alright, so you don't have the `needed` variable, but you do have access to a `more` function that will tell you whether said `needed` variable is greater than some input? Then using only this `more` function, you wish to check whether `needed` is in range?

Comment: @Rishav Using the `more` function, I wish to check whether `current` is within said `tolerance` of the `needed` number. Basically, as close as I can get to the decimal before a break clause is implemented.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102932/discussion-between-rishav-and-shennan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to do better than a binary search for searching a number in a range.

Assuming the range will always be know/similar, validation can be done before the search() function either with the use of your more() function or a clamp function. See this link [clamp number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409895/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-cap-a-number-to-a-segment)

If the range can change dramatically, some kind of exponential function could be used to find 'the good range'.

- Range 0-100
- Range 101 to 1000
- Range 1001 to 20000
- etc.

You could also considerate setting your tolerance as a percentage, or as a number of 'good decimals'. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874964/binary-search-to-guess-real-numbers)

Know that you will get the same efficacity while searching for a number with x decimals (ie. 123.45 in a range 0 to 1000) and while searching for 12345 in a range 0 to 100 000.

Since the 'worst case scenario' number of tries is ⌈log2(n+1)⌉. Having a 100 tries allows you to find a number precisely in a range of 0 to n = 1267650600228229401496703205375. Since you have decimals, for every decimal of precision you desire, you need to divide this number by 10.

A 0.xxxxxx precision would leave you with a 0 to 12676506002282294014967032 range in which you would find your number in less than 100 tries.

If my calculations are correct..

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, would you say that the code I've written (after your suggestion of the clamp check at the beginning) is a relatively solid implementation of a binary search?

Comment: Yes it seems like a solid implementation.

Comment: This answer has been the most helpful, and it's interesting to see the calculations you've outlined. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When binary searching on a real interval, there is no need to check for equality, but instead you keep refining the search interval till it's sufficiently small.

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.10.0
(function() {
  var eps, hi, lo, mid, more, secret;

  // This is your tolerance value.
  eps = 0.01;

  // The binary search routine will never get to see this.
  secret = 45.63;

  more = function(test) {
    return test > secret;
  };

  lo = 0;

  hi = 100;

  while (hi - lo > eps) {
    mid = lo + ((hi - lo) / 2);
    if (more(mid)) {
      hi = mid;
    } else {
      lo = mid;
    }
  }

  console.log(mid);

}).call(this);
```

Output: `45.635986328125`

---

On out of range values, the output will be equal to `lo` or `hi`, where equal means that their absolute difference will be less than `eps`.

---

See also: [Binary searching on real numbers: Topcoder](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-search/).

> ```
> binary_search(lo, hi, p):
>    while we choose not to terminate:
>       mid = lo + (hi-lo)/2
>       if p(mid) == true:
>          hi = mid
>       else:
>          lo = mid
>
>      return lo // lo is close to the border between no and yes
> ```
>
> Since the set of real numbers is dense, it should be clear that we usually won’t be able to find the exact target value. However, we can quickly find some x such that f(x) is within some tolerance of the border between no and yes. We have two ways of deciding when to terminate: terminate when the search space gets smaller than some predetermined bound (say 10^-12) or do a fixed number of iterations.

Comment: This breaks when eps is zero, which I think is a lesser implementation. I prefer an implementation that breaks the loop after a certain amount of tries. That way, if the number is guessable within a certain number of steps, it'll be bang-on point. Thanks for putting the time in though, others may find this useful.